# scheme question code don't know why wrong

Tags: scheme

I want to solve the scheme problem

I define the code two, three, sq, plus

two is f(f(x)) // three is f(f(f(x)))

sq is square function ex ((two sq)3) is 81

plus is

```
(define (plus m n)
             (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (m f (n f x))
```

[image]

I don't know why wrong that please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing arity of functions. `three` and `two` are not functions of two parameters. They are functions that take a parameter and return a function. That returned function again takes a parameter.
Try the evaluating the following:

```
(let ((inc (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
  (list ((three inc) 0)
        ((two inc) 0)))
```

Your plus should be:

```
(define (plus m n)
  (lambda (f) (lambda (x) ((m f) ((n f) x)))))
```

Now this should give you `(3 2 5)`

```
(let ((inc (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
  (list ((three inc) 0)
    ((two inc) 0)
    (((plus two three) inc) 0)))
```

Comment: thank you friends but I mean two and three is f(x)^2 ,f(x)^3